# When Restricted Google Places API Key with iOS bundle identifier, nearby search doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, api-key, google-nearby

I have integrated Google maps in my application and I want to show nearby restaurants in my app. So I've used Google places nearby search API for that. There is key for this API in the console. When I restrict that key for iOS app only with its  bundle identifier, the nearby search API doesn't work. When I remove the restriction, it works fine. What am I missing? Is there any parameter I need to pass during calling of API?

Comment: Are you getting 403?

Comment: please let me know if my answer didn't work with you, otherwise accept it as answer please

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass your bundle-id in the request header:

```
"X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier":"Your bundle id"
```